# Create file exe from chrome Apps

Tags: google-chrome-extension, exe, google-chrome-app

I have a chrome Apps and uploaded to store. 
I am trying to make A .exe file which will install
The Apps in chrome browser at app launcher when i run it.
Any ideas how this can be done ?

My Apps:

> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cloud-monitor/ginncgomgmdfjbopknmdhnhefjemidih

Comment: What is a "chrome application"? There are Chrome Apps and Chrome Extensions. You refer to an extension, so perhaps you are asking about an Extension and not an App? Please remove the tag that doesn't apply.

Comment: Sorry! I provide incomplete information , so do you misunderstood . I want to ask about chrome apps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, by [writing to the registry](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions#registry).

Note that the extension/app **must** be published in the Store for this to work.

Also, it will install the extension/app when the browser is restarted, and the user will be asked to confirm they want that extension/app installed.

Comment: Does this work for Chrome Apps? The doc doesn't say so.

Comment: Somebody should test this before this is taken as the answer, because the OP asked about Chrome Apps.